# How to change row color in datagridview by comparing two columns from different tables using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, vb.net-2010

No success!

[image]

If user of `tblcon` with billmonth of `tbltrns` exists in `tbltrns` then highlight the rows of `tblcon` with red color

Code:

```
 Private Sub checkexist()

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

        ConObj = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
        ConObj.Open()
        Dim qry As String = "SELECT * FROM tblTrns WHERE userName=@userName and bill_month=@bill_month"
        CmdObj = New SqlCommand(qry, ConObj)
        CmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bill_month", DateTimePicker1.Text)
        CmdObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", (row.Cells("User").Value.ToString))

        drObj = CmdObj.ExecuteReader()

    If drObj.HasRows Then
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red

    End If
    Next

   ConObj.Close()
End Sub
```

Query for the Grid

```
 Public Function GetData() As DataView

    ConObj = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
    ConObj.Open()
    CmdObj = New SqlCommand
    dsObj = New DataSet
    daObj = New SqlDataAdapter()

    Dim SelectQry = "SELECT UserName[User],doj[Connection Date],packagename[Package],profilename[Profile],billing[Payment],fees[Fees],connectionstatus[Status] from TblCon"

    CmdObj.CommandText = SelectQry
    CmdObj.Connection = ConObj
    daObj.SelectCommand = CmdObj
    daObj.Fill(dsObj)
    TvObj = dsObj.Tables(0).DefaultView

    Return TvObj
    ConObj.Close()

End Function
```

Query Changed in getdata but no success. Please guide ...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```
Public Function GetData() As DataView

    ConObj = New SqlConnection(ConStr)
    ConObj.Open()
    CmdObj = New SqlCommand
    dsObj = New DataSet
    daObj = New SqlDataAdapter()

    Dim SelectQry = Dim SelectQry = "SELECT UserName[User],doj[Connection Date],packagename[Package],profilename[Profile],billing[Payment],fees[Fees],conn‌​‌​‌​ectionstatus[Status], (SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) FROM tblTrns WHERE tblTrns.userName = tblCon.UserName AND bill_month = '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "') [Comparison] from TblCon"

    CmdObj.CommandText = SelectQry
    CmdObj.Connection = ConObj
    daObj.SelectCommand = CmdObj
    daObj.Fill(dsObj)
    TvObj = dsObj.Tables(0).DefaultView

    Return TvObj
    ConObj.Close()

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to fill a new column in your grid with a value for comparison and set it's visibility to false.
You can do that by a subselect or a left join on the second table (if you wish an example just post the query that fills your grid).

Based on your comparison column you can use the CellPainting event of the GridView. Like this:

```
Private Sub grdGridView_CellPainting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs) Handles grdGridView.CellPainting
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then

        If grdGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("colComparison").Value <> "0" And Not IsNothing(grdGridView.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("colComparison").Value) Then
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed
            e.CellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.IndianRed
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response sir but i really dont understand. Im new in programming so can you please explain.

Comment: Please show me the query being used to fill the Grid.

Comment: Dim SelectQry = "SELECT UserName[User],doj[Connection Date],packagename[Package],profilename[Profile],billing[Payment],fees[Fees],connectionstatus[Status] from TblCon"

Comment: Add the last field to your query, as below:
    "SELECT UserName[User],doj[Connection Date],packagename[Package],profilename[Profile],billing[Payment],fees[Fees],conn‌​ectionstatus[Status],
(SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) FROM tblTrns WHERE tblTrns.userName = tblCon.UserName AND bill_month = DateTimePicker1.Text) AS Comparison from TblCon"
    
Then use this new column as comparison, as i said before. This should work.

Comment: Sir i tried but no success. I add column with name 'comparison' in grid of tblcon then i add query in getdata sub. next i add cellpainting event. Error comes with sqlexception was unhandled. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Comment: Try changing the query as follow:
"SELECT UserName[User],doj[Connection Date],packagename[Package],profilename[Profile],billing[Payment],fees[Fees],conn‌​‌​ectionstatus[Status], (SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) FROM tblTrns WHERE tblTrns.userName = tblCon.UserName AND bill_month = DateTimePicker1.Text)[colComparison] from TblCon"

Comment: Are you concatenating DateTimePicker1.Text correctly in your query text?

Comment: Yes. Losing hope... May be i should try some different method for comparing.

Comment: Dim SelectQry = "SELECT UserName[User],doj[Connection Date],packagename[Package],profilename[Profile],billing[Payment],fees[Fees],conn‌​‌​‌​ectionstatus[Status], (SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(*), 0) FROM tblTrns WHERE tblTrns.userName = tblCon.UserName AND bill_month = '" & DateTimePicker1.Text & "') [Comparison] from TblCon"